# vscode shortcut or easier method to add a functions to class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I went up and down of the vscode documentation to find a way to automatically create functions inside the class, every time I am adding a method to a class I need to copy the definition and scroll to the bottom of the page to implement the method.

Clion had a great set of tools for this
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Generation_in_CPP.html#equality

I wonder if there is any easy way that I can use to add a function to a class without scroll up and down the file

```
class HelloWorld
{
private:
  
public:
  
  int IWantToDefineAMethod(); //<- need to scroll here and write this
};

int HelloWorld::IWantToDefineAMethod() //<-- then need to scroll to here and write this 
{

}

// and need to scroll here and there couple of time just to add a single function!
```

Comment: Just search the function? vs code has it inbuilt

Comment: There should be plugins for that. I found [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amiralizadeh9480.cpp-helper)

Comment: CLion is an IDE and VSCode is just an Editor.

Comment: @LouisGo that helps! if you add your answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amiralizadeh9480.cpp-helper

I'm not the creator and just found it.

A side note is that it creates implementation for prototype but it doesn't check if it's duplicated which is described in the *Known ISSUE* section.

You need to set `CppHelper.SourcePattern` to let plugin knows where should it search for source file.

```
Example:

"CppHelper.SourcePattern": [
    "{FILE}.cpp",
    "{FILE}.c",
    "{FILE}.inl",
    "/src/{FILE}.cpp"
]
Where {FILE} is your active header file name.
```